# "net" package import error in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to run a sample Go program that I found on the net, which is given below:

```
/* IP */

package main

import (
    "net"
    "os"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) != 2 {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Usage: %s ip-addr\n", os.Args[0])
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    name := os.Args[1]

    addr := net.ParseIP(name)
    if addr == nil {
        fmt.Println("Invalid address")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("The address is ", addr.String())
    }
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

Then I try to compile it using:

```
6g ip.go
```

and I get the following error:

```
ip.go:7: can't find import: net
```

Does my go version not have a net package? or am I using a wrong version of compiler? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are still using the `6g` compiler command then I assume you are not using the [recent Go1 stable release](http://golang.org/doc/install)? It would depend on the version you are actually running. "net" is a valid package: http://golang.org/pkg/net/

Recommended that you install the latest Go.

```
$ go run ip.go 127.0.0.1
The address is  127.0.0.1
```

You can see that the go playground, using Go 1, works:
http://play.golang.org/p/rXSep9GH-U

Comment: thanks, i will check that out, i suspected that i wasn't using the latest package, but i thought that net package would be integral to even the first version of go

Comment: The package naming scheme was altered/reorganised not long before the release of Go1.